# Pass in runtimeType as generic function parameter

Tags: swift, dart, generic-programming

I am a Swift developer and new to Dart. I am trying to write some generic method.

I would like to know if I can achieve similar thing like this in Dart.

```
//Swift version

public func modelFrom<T: Mappable>(response: Encodable?, model: T.Type) -> T? {

    if let response = response, let string = response.jsonString {
        return T(JSONString: string)
    }

    return nil

}

// The method can be called like this

let responseModel = modelFrom(response: response, model: FoodLogModel.self)
```

For Dart, can I cast the type of the generic class? like `<T: Mappable>` in Swift?

Is `runtimeType` in Dart equivalent to `<ClassName>.self` in Swift?

Many thanks

Here is what I have tried,

```
import 'package:dartson/dartson.dart';
import 'package:mobile_corelib/base/model.dart';

T requestFrom<T>(BaseModel model, Type T) {

  try {

    var dson = new Dartson.JSON();
    var object = dson.map(dson.encode(model), T.runtimeType);

    return object;
  } catch(error) {
    return null;
  }
}
var dick = requestFrom(model, AccessTokenRequest().runtimeType)
```

But I don't know how to pass in the `Class type`. Should I use `dynamic`? or `Type`

Comment: Have you tried it in Dart? What was the problem?

Comment: updated question. thanks

Comment: So you want to deserialize JSON to instances of a concrete type? I haven't used Dartson, but I'd expect it to explain how to do that in it's Readme or demonstrate it in an example. You can pass the type as `requestFrom<AccessTokenRequest>(model)`, but you can't use `new T(json)` because Dart currently doesn't have interfaces for static methods or constructors.

Answer (score 3):

`runtimeType` in Dart is a value of type `Type`, which is not the same thing as what happens when you write a type in a generic type parameter.

As an example, `new List<String>()` is valid, but `new List<''.runtimeType>()` is a syntax error.

Generally, `Type` is quite limited. You can't use it to create new instances--unless you're in the VM, where you can use mirrors.